# Opposite direction of polymorphic association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have an example in my app where I'm able to assign/access polymorphic association but am I not able to access the class back from the polymorphic association,

```
class EmailCampaignSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscribable, polymorphic: true
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :email_campaign_subscription, as: :subscribable
end
```

This works `EmailCampaignSubscription.last.subscribable` but this does not `Order.last. email_campaign_subscription`. Also this does not work :

`EmailCampaignSubscription.last.subscribable.email_campaign_subscription`

By does not work I mean it returns `nil`.

This works (returns the correct record):

```
EmailCampaignSubscription.where(subscribable_type: "Order", subscribable_id: Order.last.id)
```

I am using rails `4.2.11`, why does this accessor back to `email_campaign_subscription` does not work and how can I fix the association definition to make it work?

**Update:**

I tried this :

```
has_one :email_campaign_subscription, class_name: 'EmailCampaignSubscription', as: :subscribable
```

Still got `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `class_name` option with polymorphic `has_one`

```
has_one :email_campaign_subscription, class_name: 'EmailCampaignSubscription', 
                                      as: :subscribable
```

Give it a try.